# Данные из полей неотправленной формы

Tags: html, jquery, ajax, form, input

Пользователь зашёл на сайт, ввел данные (напр. имя, телефон и т.п.), но по каким то причинам не отправил их, как можно получить данные из форм? Думаю в сторону `ajax` с записью в БД.
Каждому пользователю при заходе индивидуальный id в cookie, и уже в БД отправлять, но вопрос в том как грамотнее всего сделать отправку, не выполнять ведь скрипт по `keyup` в каждом поле? Поделитесь опытом и идеями на этот счет

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Обрабатывайте событие `focusout`, например.

Comment: идея то что нужно, благодарю